# When is nilradical not a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

[image: Atiyah gives this criterion for nilradical to be an ideal]

Atiyah gives this criterion for nilradical to be a prime ideal.Nilradical is the intersection of prime ideals.Is nilradical prime iff there is only one prime ideal? ie Intersection of distinct prime ideals can never be a prime ideal?

Comment: nilradical is intersection of prime ideals. so if there is more than one minimal prime ideal, then nilradical is not a prime ideal

Comment: Can you give an example of a ring with only one prime ideal

Comment: Basurya: any field has  only one prime ideal.

Comment: nilradical is always an ideal.

Comment: Intersection of distinct prime ideals can never be a prime ideal?ie Is nilradical prime iff there is only one prime ideal?

Comment: if $p_1 \cap p_2 = p$ then $p_1 p_2 \subset p$ then $p_1 \subset p$ or $ p_2 \subset p$

Comment: @Basurya Another example of a ring with exactly one prime ideal (but 
isn't a field) is $F[x]/(x^k)$ for any fixed $k>1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nilradical is intersection of prime ideals. So if there is more than one minimal prime ideal, then nilradical is not a prime ideal.
note that Intersection of distinct minimal prime ideals can never be a prime ideal because if $p_1\cap... \cap p_n = p$ then $p_1... p_n \subset p$  so $p_i \subset p$  for some i. this means $p=p_i$

Answer (score 8):

Take $A:=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy)$.